# displaying (result of Show function)

Tags: plotting

I used Show to represent some functions. I want the displaying box to start and end by (0, 40) in the x-direction and (0,100) in y-axis. I mean I don't want the little separation between zero and vertical axis below pic:
[exmple for show function result](https://pictub.club/image/swxPOH)

Comment: It is a good idea to post some of the code you are using as an example.

Comment: Sara, you've been here for some time and asked several questions. Have you ever considered going through any tutorial to learn the basics? In most of your questions you just throw a demand ("I want to have something...") or, like in this case, don't provide any code, any proper description of what you'd want to achieve and where exactly you failed. We don't read minds, unless you introduce us in full extent to your problem, we won't be guessing what do you mean. You were told on several occassions to make your questions clear and self-consistent, and still fail to conform.

Comment: In addition to @corey979 's comment, [The Wolfram Language: Fast Introduction for Programmers](http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers) is a good guide if you are already familiar with programming concepts. The guide is available in 8 languages, and you can enable notes that compare the Wolfram Language to Java or Python.

Comment: If you are new to programming in general, [*An Elementary Introduction to the Wolfram Language*](http://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/) by Stephen Wolfram is a good online book to read. This one is linked to interactive Wolfram Cloud documents in which you can learn and try Wolfram Language functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you are referring to `PlotRangePadding`. Just disable it:

```
Plot[-.3 x^2 + 10 x, {x, 0, 40}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 40}, {0, 100}}, PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

You can use the same commands for `Show` as well.

[image]

Comment: I want to use Show function to display some figures. Because for some of my figures I have used ListContourPlot instead of grph

Comment: I edited the comment @corey979

Answer (score 3):

Try the 'PlotRange" command.

```
Plot[x^2/16, {x, 0, 40}, PlotRange -> {{0, 40}, {0, 100}}, Frame -> True]
```