# Gap in X-axis when using LogLinearPlot

Tags: plotting

Basically, this is the plot that comes out when I choose

```
Frame -> True
```

Due to my need of labeling the axes. Is there a way to get rid off of that annoying gap?

Here is the figure

[image]

Here is the code (it won't work because you did not define the functions I used). Just, please, tell me how to solve it (I guess it does occur independently upon the function I plot).

```
LogLinearPlot[{L[0.25], L[0.5], L[0.75], L[1]}, {z, 0.1, 10}, 
PlotRange -> {0, 2},
PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
PlotStyle -> {{Black}, {Black, Dotted}, {Black, Dashed}, {Black, 
DotDashed}}, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13}, AxesStyle -> Bold, 
Frame -> True,  FrameLabel -> {Log[t], Subscript[Ein, \[Nu]][t]}]
```

Comment: Can you then come up with an example *other* people can run that exhibits the same problem?

Comment: Use `PlotRange->{{0.1, 2}, {0,2}}` to control the x and y ranges independenty.

Comment: First, post a complete code that reproduces your issue. If it's too big, make an MWE. Second, nothing in the plot you posted annoys me. **Describe** what is the issue. Don't expect people to guess what you have in mind.

Comment: @corey979 - even though OP didn't post a MWE, here is one: `LogLinearPlot[x, {x, 0.1, 10}, Frame -> True]`  The annoying gap is the fact that the x-range of the plot extends to the left beyond the plotrange.  Normally, you don't expect the x-range that's plotted to go beyond what is input.  If you try that in version 11, it works the right way.  For version 10, you have to use Carl's method.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue has been fixed in the latest version of *Mathematica* and a workaround is simple in other versions.

Comment: @Feyre I do agree!

Comment: Personally I'd rather someone edit the question to make it self-contained.  If the minimum example I mentioned above really does describe the problem, it can be used.  There are plenty of questions on here that don't apply to the latest version, and are useful for people searching in the future.  The solution is simple, but not necessarily obvious.  My first fix was to use a negative value for the `PlotRangePadding`, an obvious hack.  Then I saw Carl's response and smacked my forehead

Comment: @JasonB Another recent related question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/135719/121 -- I am inclined to agree we should make a canonical post about this as it seems to come up fairly often.